# gpt partition for raid 6 that was 4.5TB, will i have any issues under server 2008 64bit r2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, storage, ntfs, best-practices, gpt

has anyone had any issues with using one large gpt partition of 5TB on a raid 6 setup with a 3ware raid controller. i am using the partition as a basic file sharing backup repository, nothing fancy. are there any limitations to using gpt under ntfs that i should be concerned about? the other option would be to split the array into 2TB ones and make non gpt. if further info is needed i can provide. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine. I'll just throw out the usual warnings:

- Too many files in a single directory (seems ~50k per directory is a colloquially accepted "safe" limit)
- Monitor the system, using large SATA disks causes rebuilds to really tax the system and usually take a whole day or more to rebuild. The error rate during something like that is *approaching* whole percentage numbers (most people don't really like the idea that 1 in 100 rebuilds will irreconcilably fail).
- For any new controller, make sure you get the latest firmware and drivers. Burning the drives in for a couple days to weed out infant death is a good idea too.

Comment: i agree that a large 6TB raid 5 would be maybe close to 4% for another drive to die in a rebuild, but with raid 6 the percent goes down to 0.4% or something like that, that is two drives to die in the rebuild process. As a rule i keep my raid arrays in a raid 6 to no more than 8 drives and 1.5TB per drive, if i need more or have more drives like 16 drives, i would do a raid 6 but do it with two arrays with 8 drives each. others can chime in on this.